# ¿Cómo devolver el match, incluyendo los espacios correspondientes?

Tags: javascript, regex

Esta función me devuelve el String con solo **digitos o letras**, según lo que se le pase como parámetro, el problema es que el método `match()` no me devuelve los espacios correspondientes. Éste es mi código:

```js
String.prototype.filtro = function(filtro){
  var a = filtro.toLowerCase();
  if(a != 'numeros' && a != 'letras') return 'Parámetro inválido';
  var patron = a == 'numeros' ? /[0-9]/ig : /[a-z]/ig;
 
  return this.match(patron).join("");
  
};


var b = "hola como estas $^^´ç+$".filtro("letras");
console.log(b);
```

Lo que **espero que devuelva** es: `"hola como estas"`, pero me devuelve `"holacomoestas"`, ¿qué debo hacer?

Además intenté con el `.join(" ")` , separándolo con un espacio, pero como `match` devuelve el array separando letra por letra, me devuelve **cada letra con espacios**.

Comment: `/[a-z\s]/ig` o solo un espacio `/[a-z ]/ig`

Comment: Habia intentado con \s , pero no dentro del rango, sino que fuera, por qué va dentro ? y gracias podrías ponerlo de respuesta

Comment: Por la misma razón que colocas `a-z`  quieres que coincida con valores entre a-z y además espacios , si lo coloca fuera del grupo validará que después de cualquier letra exista un espacio , el resultado será  la letra final de cada palabra separada por espacio

Comment: Porque una clase de caracteres (lo que está entre corchetes) no es un rango, sino un caracter con el que puede coincidir... Otra alternativa es reemplazar todo lo que no es letras o espacios por una cadena vacía con `this.replace(/[^a-záéíóúüñ ]+/ig,"");`

Comment: En que afecta el metacaracter + ? , no lo he agregado y no me afecto

Comment: Repite la construcción anterior 1 o más veces... Es decir, coincide con 1 o más caracteres dentro de la clase... Te recomiendo leer sobre la sintaxis de expresiones regulares en https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con expresiones regulares podrían haber al menos dos opciones

```
/[a-z\s]/ig
```

Donde `\s` hace referencia a (espacios en blanco, tab, salto de página, salto de linea y retorno de carro), o añadiendo un espacio al final de la clase de caracteres

```
/[a-z ]/ig
```

además se añadió al grupo los acentos y la ñ `áéíóúüñ` que hay que tener en cuenta en estos casos.

```js
String.prototype.filtro = function(filtro){
  var a = filtro.toLowerCase();
  if(a != 'numeros' && a != 'letras') return 'Parámetro inválido';
  var patron = a == 'numeros' ? /[0-9]/ig : /[a-záéíóúüñ ]/ig;
 
  return this.match(patron).join("");
  
};


var b = "Hola cómo estas $^^´ç+$".filtro("letras");
console.log(b);
```